# Entity Framework creates different SQL depending on where program is run

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have created a small C# console application which only task is to parse an XML-file and put the result into a database table. Im using Entity framework 6.0 and .NET 4.

All is fine when i run it on my local computer (Win7) but when i am running it on the server (WS2008R2) it crashes. It is the exact same files just copy/pasted to the server (i.e same Database etc.).

Debugging shows that the SQL-query is created differently by Entity Framework depending on in which environment it is executed. (see below)

**ON LOCAL COMPUTER (Works fine):**

```
INSERT [dbo].[Accessories]([Id], [Name], [Category], [Price], [Description], [Phone_Id])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, NULL)
@0: '1018' (Type = Int32)
@1: 'H141/A Headset Duoset' (Type = String, Size = -1)
@2: 'Headset Fixed Lines' (Type = String, Size = -1)
@3: '1563' (Type = Int32)
@4: 'H141/A DuoSet™, Plantronics headset.' (Type = String, Size = -1)
Executing 
Completed in 19 ms with result: 1
```

**ON SERVER (Doesn´t work):**

```
INSERT [dbo].[Accessories]([Name], [Category], [Price], [Description], [Phone_Id])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, NULL)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Accessories]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()
@0: 'H141/A Headset Duoset' (Type = String, Size = -1)
@1: 'Headset Fixed Lines' (Type = String, Size = -1)
@2: '1563' (Type = Int32)
@3: 'H141/A DuoSet™, Plantronics headset.' (Type = String, Size = -1)
Executing 
Failed in 1 ms with error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'Sales.dbo.Accessories'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

**ACTUAL CODE IN APPLICATION:**

```
           try
           {
               XmlNodeList xNodeList = xDoc.SelectNodes("accessories/child::node()");
               foreach (XmlNode xNode in xNodeList)
               {
                   if (xNode.Name == "accessory")
                   {
                       var accessory = new Accessory();
                       accessory.Id = Convert.ToInt32(xNode.Attributes["id"].Value);
                       foreach (XmlNode childNode in xNode.ChildNodes)
                       {
                           if (childNode.Name == "name")
                           {
                               accessory.Name = childNode.InnerText;
                           }
                           if (childNode.Name == "category")
                           {
                               accessory.Category = childNode.InnerText;
                           }
                           if (childNode.Name == "description")
                           {
                               accessory.Description = childNode.InnerText;
                           }
                           if (childNode.Name == "price")
                           {
                               accessory.Price = Convert.ToInt32(childNode.InnerText);
                           }
                       }
                       _db.Add(accessory);
                   }
               }
               _db.SaveChanges();
```

The SQL-server is MSSQL.

I am a little lost here.. what to do?

Comment: Are you aware that SQL Server has different versions? Check them - I am sure you have different versions on both sides. THe DB side is not  identical.

Comment: As a side comment, you could probably replace that whole function with some nice Linq to XML.

Comment: Could you please post the Accessory class and the corresponding mapping if you have one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution to our problem, I'm not sure why, but here it is:

We had forgot to set the database intializer.

```
Database.SetInitializer(new CustomContextInitializer());
```

which now calls on:

```
public class CustomContextInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<CustomProjectContext>
{        
    public void InitializeDatabase(CustomProjectContext context)
    {
        context.Database.Initialize(false);
    }
}
```

I guess Entity or .NET is doing some own background operations if this part is missing, thats why we got different SQL on different environments.

Answer (score 0):

I think your server version of the database doesn't have the Identity Specification set to Yes for your primary key (Id). So it is not auto-generating an Id number and, since you're not passing it through, that is why it is erroring on the null Id.

Comment: No, the OP is passing through an ID, it's Entity Framework that's stripping it out. See the OP's SQL that gets generated on the local computer: the ID is filled in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Code First (and I'm pretty sure you are), then beware that different versions of Entity Framework (*not* different versions of SQL Server) use subtly different rules for mapping classes to tables. One thing that depends on the exact EF version is whether an integer property `Id` is automatically, without any specification on your part, mapped to an `IDENTITY` column in the database. If your database was created with `Id` as a regular non-identity column, and your code changed EF versions so that it now expects an identity column, things break.

The solution is to not mix EF versions. Pick one version, and stick with it. Make sure that version is the one you're using on your local computer, and also the one you're using on the server. Make sure that version of the Entity Framework DLLs is copied to your program's installation directory, don't rely on anything installed globally.

Comment: Did the following:
* Upgraded EF to 6.1.1
* Dropped database
* Recreated database (using EF)
* Deleted all files on server
* Copied all files from local bin to server (including EF dll)

Same result as before, executing locally works, executing on server fails... :(

Comment: @Gruffalon That's odd. And if you now trace to get the queries that actually get executed, are they still different between local machine and server, and still the same as what you originally saw? Can you make sure, by checking the properties of `typeof(DbContext).Assembly`, that the Entity Framework DLL that gets loaded is indeed the one that you want to get loaded?

Comment: Checked assembly and it is EF 6.0.0.0 on both server and local client. The SQL generates the same way as before (different on server than local client). Could it be an OLE DB provider issue? There are many more providers on local client i.e SQL Server Native Client 10 and 11.

Comment: @Gruffalon That shouldn't make a difference. (But, nothing that you haven't already ruled out should make a difference, so that's not saying too much...)

Comment: Another thing is that i also run the same code/assembly in an web application on a IIS web server on the same server, and that is working just fine, but maby EF is handled differently running under IIS?